# html objects don't float?

Tags: html, css

I am building site using Amazon affiliate. Most of their widgets are `<objects>` and I populate appropriate `<divs>` on my site and then try to position this but without success. Is it impossible to float object containing divs??

```
<div id='slidebar-primary'>
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab" id="Player_e3463c6b-61ad-4bdc-bf9a-ba74d3d1cbd2"  WIDTH="728px" HEIGHT="90px"> <PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE="http://ws.amazon.ca/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%2Fcraigslist068-20%2F8009%2Fe3463c6b-61ad-4bdc-bf9a-ba74d3d1cbd2&Operation=GetDisplayTemplate"><PARAM NAME="quality" VALUE="high"><PARAM NAME="bgcolor" VALUE="#FFFFFF"><PARAM NAME="allowscriptaccess" VALUE="always"><embed src="http://ws.amazon.ca/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%2Fcraigslist068-20%2F8009%2Fe3463c6b-61ad-4bdc-bf9a-ba74d3d1cbd2&Operation=GetDisplayTemplate" id="Player_e3463c6b-61ad-4bdc-bf9a-ba74d3d1cbd2" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" name="Player_e3463c6b-61ad-4bdc-bf9a-ba74d3d1cbd2" allowscriptaccess="always"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" align="middle" height="90px" width="728px"></embed></OBJECT> <NOSCRIPT><A HREF="http://ws.amazon.ca/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%2Fcraigslist068-20%2F8009%2Fe3463c6b-61ad-4bdc-bf9a-ba74d3d1cbd2&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.ca Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
</div>
<div id='recommend-right'>
<SCRIPT charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ws.amazon.ca/widgets/q?rt=tf_mfw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822/CA/craigslist068-20/8001/44dd2f66-ebef-4397-a6ab-d60dd98d9783"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT><A HREF="http://ws.amazon.ca/widgets/q?rt=tf_mfw&ServiceVersion=20070822&MarketPlace=CA&ID=V20070822%2FCA%2Fcraigslist068-20%2F8001%2F44dd2f66-ebef-4397-a6ab-d60dd98d9783&Operation=NoScript">Amazon.ca Widgets</A></NOSCRIPT>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#slidebar-main{ float:left; }
```

And no working as they are just one on top other. Please, help?? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere in that code does the div id `slidebar-main` exist.

Try changing it to

```
div#slidebar-primary { float: left; }
```

Comment: Also set a width on the div. It may be defaulting to 100% so even after floating they will display underneath each other. If floating one doesn't put them side-by-side, set widths on both (together equaling less than the parent's width) and float both.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you've written doesn't match your HTML (there's no element called `#slidebar-main`). Does this not work?

```
#slidebar-primary, #recommend-right {float: left;}
```